# Ruby OpenSSL Errors - Missing CA Certs (Who is Justin?)

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl, https, openssl

I'm writing a little utility script that deals with some RESTful API's over HTTPS using Ruby's Net::HTTP module on Windows. I consistently get this error:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
```

According to [this post](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/07/ruby-openssl/) I'm missing the default CA Certs. I ran his "ssl doctor" script and it gave me this diagnostic:

```
C:\Users\Megaflux\Documents\GitHub\Github_Backup> ruby doctor.rb
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby (2.2.2-p95)
OpenSSL 1.0.1l 15 Jan 2015: C:/Users/Justin/Projects/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x64-windows/openssl/1.0.1l/ssl
SSL_CERT_DIR=""
SSL_CERT_FILE=""

HEAD https://status.github.com:443
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

The server presented a certificate that could not be verified:
  subject: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
  issuer: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
  error code 20: unable to get local issuer certificate

Possible causes:
  `C:/Users/Justin/Projects/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x64-windows/openssl/1.0.1l/ssl/cert.pem' does not exist
  `C:/Users/Justin/Projects/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x64-windows/openssl/1.0.1l/ssl/certs/' is empty
```

I'm fine downloading some root CA certificates and installing them at that directory, which isn't hard. But who is Justin? I don't have that user on my machine, and I'd rather not create those folders if I don't have to. Does anyone know how to change the default ssl certificate directory?

Many thanks.

Edit:
For completeness, I'll throw the script that was generating the error down here

```
require 'open-uri'
open("https://www.google.com/") {|f|
   f.each_line {|line| p line}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm Justin =) Seriously though this problem pops up constantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RubyInstaller issue #153](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/153)

> ## OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE with personal hardcoded path
>
> The problem is OpenSSL that has hardcoded values. Search to closed
>   issues and also RubyInstaller group and will see this happens from
>   time to time.
>
> OpenSSL needs to be fixed, but no patch to solve this issue has
>   proposed to OpenSSL itself. See [oneclick/rubyinstaller#47](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/pull/47)
>
> cert.pem is already provided by RubyGems and is included, please take
>   a look here:
>
> https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/ruby_2_0_0/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs
>
> That is part of Ruby and thus, RubyInstaller release.
>
> RubyGems is capable of installing gems from rubygems.org, however,
>   like you pointed in the Bundler issue, you need a list of other CAs so
>   connect to the private/custom RubyGems server works.
>
> For that you need to set `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable pointing
>   to the CA certs file.
>
> See [oneclick/rubyinstaller#86](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/pull/86) and [oneclick/rubyinstaller#148](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/pull/148)

tl;dr: Justin is the person who compiled your OpenSSL binary.

Comment: Yeah, I just read that. The dumb person that I am, I didn't think to search for the actual path "C:\Users\Justin" in my Google escapades until just now

Comment: I'll leave the question up for posterity, though.

Comment: Just an FYI for anybody else whose quest to debug this leads them here, note that though the issue says that setting the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variables fixes the issue, this does not work for all versions of SSL i.e. it did not work for my install of Ruby 2.1.8 via Rails Installer

Comment: It's not just for posterity. Some gems (e.g. the Zendesk App Tools) still depend on older versions of Ruby, which apparently don't have the fixed RubyInstaller.